# When do I have to use 'this' when using C++ constructors?

Tags: c++

```
class Int {
    int n;

public:

    Int(int n) {
        this->n = n;
    }

};
```

vs

```
class Int {
    int n;

public:

    Int(int n) : n(n){
    }

};
```

What is essentially the difference between these two and when should one use the `this` keyword when creating a new object of a given class?

Comment: And the second syntax is called *"Member initialization list"* in case you did not know.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest difference is the second one is the recommended way as it avoids double-initializing properties. An `int` is a trivial case, but you can imagine you might have some expensive structure in there that would get initialized twice:

```
Complicated(const HeavyObject& _h) : h(_h) {
  // h only initialized once
}

Complicated(const HeavyObject& _h) {
  // h already initialized with default constructor

  // Copy to object, potentially initializing all over again.
  this->h = _h;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit of a nitpick, but `this->h = _h` is an assignment, not an initialization, although your point about not constructing twice is correct.

Comment: I prefer the postfix version `h_` since prefix `_` seems to be reserved for internals (questionable if this rule could ever apply to parameters, but well for sake of consistency).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, I've seen some wildly different standards for internal vs external naming conventions. This is just an example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As long as it's just a single underscore followed by a lowercase letter in a non-global scope, it's fine. But I don't like it either.

Comment: In `template` s, the `this` pointer is required in certain scenarios irrespective of constructors or member methods. BTW, the example you have given doesn't require `this` necessarily as the variable names are different.

Comment: @Baum I mostly use the postfix `_` for class member variables anyway (thus it's the other way round regarding the parameters), because it lets me smoothly provide getter and setter functions named `int h() const;` and `void h(int);`.